# Identifying common elements in multiple files

Tags: python, perl, shell

I have 8 files of one column and non uniform number of rows in each column. I need to identify the elements which are common in all of these 8 files.

I can do this task for comparing two files, but I am unable to write workable one liner in shell to do the same.

Any ideas.....

Thank you in advance.

File 1 
Paul 
pawan

File 2 
Raman 
Paul
sweet 
barua

File 3
Sweet
barua
Paul

The answer of the comparison of these three files should be Paul.

Comment: how large are the files? Can you keep them all in memory at the same time?

Comment: It would be nice to see an attempt

Comment: Can there be duplicate words in the same file? I.e. causing false matches if all the file data is concatenated and counted?

Comment: @ Zaid: I failed with multiple files and ran out of options.

Comment: @TLP: No repetition of elements in each file all are unique elements within a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
python -c 'import sys;print "".join(sorted(set.intersection(*[set(open(a).readlines()) for a in sys.argv[1:]])))' File1 File2 File3
```

prints `Paul` for your files `File1`, `File2` and `File3`.

Comment: Totally, ripped my answer i was working on. :D Btw, `"\n".join` should be better, IMO. and no need to sort since the set will be sorted.

Comment: @st0le - `"\n".join` inserts extra newlines, while `.readlines` keeps them within the strings, so you don't need the extra `"\n"`. And `set` is not automatically sorted.

Comment: `import sys;print"".join(reduce(set.intersection, map(set, map(open, sys.argv[1:]))))`

Comment: how would you edit this so the outputted file would be:

Paul 3
Sweet 2
barua 2
Ramen 1

so basically a list of all the strings and how many files they are common in, possible sorted by to 10

Answer (score 8):

The following one-liner should do (change 3 to 8 to match your case)

```
$ sort * | uniq -c | grep 3
      3 Paul
```

Probably better to do this in python though, using `sets`...

Comment: Returns the same if one line is three times in one file and not at all in the others.

Comment: @eumiro, true; **know your input** and select the best method for it. As I said: "python and `set` is probably the best solution" but you posted that one :-)

Comment: Of course, `grep 3` should be `grep 8` in the case with 8 files. And it should be `grep "^ *8 "` to omit lines that have numbers in them. And an additional `| sed -e "s/^ *8 //"` removes the superfluous count at the beginning of the result.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl

```
$ perl -lnE '$c{$_}{$ARGV}++ }{ print for grep { keys %{$c{$_}} == 8 } keys %c;' file[1-8]
```

It should be possible to get rid of the hard-coded `8` as well with `@{[ glob "@ARGV" ]}` but I don't have time to test it now.

This solution will correctly handle the existence of duplicate lines across files as well.

Comment: You can use a BEGIN block to count the files.

Comment: Awesome. Now, how do I do that for a BEGIN block? =)

Comment: Now it's working. Though I think you should add `-l` to both perform chomp, and do away with 5.10 reliance for `say`.

Comment: @TLP : I like your suggestion. Nice to see it works across the `END` block as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here I've been trying to find a concise way to make sure each match comes from a different file. If there are no duplicates within the files, it's fairly simple in perl:

```
perl -lnwE '$a{$_}++; END { for (keys %a) { print if $a{$_} == 3 } }' files*
```

The `-l` option will auto-chomp your input (remove newline), and add a newline to the print. This is important in case of missing eof newlines.

The `-n` option will read input from file name arguments (or stdin).

The hash assignment will count duplicates, and the END block will print out what duplicates appeared 3 times. Change 3 to however many files you have.

If you want a slightly more flexible version, you can count the arguments in a BEGIN block.

```
perl -lnwE 'BEGIN { $n = scalar @ARGV } 
    $a{$_}++; END { for (keys %a) { print if $a{$_} == $n } }' files*
```

Comment: No need for the `BEGIN` block. Just replace `$n` with `@ARGV` or `0+@ARGV`

Comment: @TLP: I checked your first one liner with duplicates as well in two files, it works perfectly  or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '++a[$0]==3' file{1..3}.txt
Paul
```

---

### update

```
$ awk '(FILENAME SEP $0) in b{next}; b[FILENAME,$0]=1 && ++a[$0]==3' file{1..3}.txt
Paul
```

Comment: Returns the same if one line is three times in one file and not at all in the others.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
ls file{1..3} | 
xargs -n1 sort -u | 
sort | 
uniq -c | 
sed 's/^\s*'"$(ls file{1..3} | wc -l)"'\s*//p;d'
```